# MATLAB: changing color of line in a while loop

Tags: matlab, plot

I am plotting a figure in Matlab. I am doing this in a while loop and I am using the figure to visualize what's happening during the loop.

For every while loop iteration, I want to change the line color so the changes in the while loops are easily monitored.

currently, I have to following code for the plot:

```
    AOAstr = num2str(AOA);
    figure(2)
    pl = plot(Span_Loc,CPcrit2,'r');
    legendStrs = {'Critical |CPpeak-CPte|'};
    set(pl,'linewidth',1.5);
    hold on
    plot(Span_Loc,CPdiff2)
    legendStrs = [legendStrs, {strcat('Local |CPpeak-CPte|','-','AOA=',AOAstr)}];
    title('Effective angle of attack')
    xlabel('semi-span')
    ylabel('|CPpeak-CPte|')
    legend('boxon')
    legend(legendStrs,'Location','SouthWest');
```

Note: the running variable in the while loop is `AOA`, hence with every iteration, AOA changes and new data on `CPdiff2` and `CPcrit2` become available. therefore, I want to plot the old data with a color, `hold on`, and then plot the data of the second while loop iteration in the same figure but with a different color for `plot(Span_Loc,CPdiff2)` while also updating the legend.

I cant figure it out, can someone help me?

Thank you!

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? Do you want the `CPcrit2` line segments to all be red and only change colour on the `CPdiff2` segments?

Comment: Hi @Dan, The CPcrit2 can be red all the time, The CPdiff2 needs to change color since its changing the most for every iteration. Currently, I am running Matlab 8.2.0.701 (R2013b)

Comment: pre 2014b, instead of `hold on` try `hold all`

Comment: @Dan, This work fine now, all the line colors are changing. However, the legend is not expanding accordingly since it only shows the last iteration and associated AOA. Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: Check the size and type of `legendStrs` after your loop, also you should only call `legend` once and it should be outside of the loop

Comment: @Dan Sorry, I cannot figure it out, my Legend now shows collors with incorrect associated AOA values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Thanushan Balakrishnan's answer is good, but you may want to have a higher control over the colors etc.

In my opinion, the best way to visualize these is using colormaps, as they are not just a single color, but a nice visual combinations of colors.

As an example, this code plots thing a bit higher than in the previous iteration each time. Up means larger `ii`

```
x=1:100;

y=rand(1,100);

num_iter=90; 
cmap=magma(num_iter); % I used my own colormap but you can use parula or something else
hold on
for ii=0:num_iter-1
    plot(x,y+ii*0.1,'color',cmap(ii+1,:));
end
```

[image]

If you can't know your number of iterations beforehand, I suggest you loop over the colormap.

One nice way of doing this is the following:

```
x=1:100;
y=rand(1,100);

num_iter=100;
cmap=magma(30); % notice, colormap is smaller
cmap=[cmap; flipud(magma(30))]; % make colormap go back to the first colro again

% now cmap is 60, but iterations are 100!

hold on
for ii=0:num_iter-1
    plot(x,y+ii*0.1,'color',cmap(mod(ii,size(cmap,1))+1,:)); 
end
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The colour of the line can be specified in `plot()` as an RGB value ([r, g, b]). The values for the r,g,b should be between 0 and 1. Hence, you can specify the colour as a function of the loop variable `AOA`.

For example you can specify the line colour like 
`plot(Span_Loc,CPdiff2, 'color', [0, AOA/255, 0])`
assuming `AOA` is never greater than 255.